# Replacing sequence of SVG transforms with a single transformation matrix

Tags: matrix, svg, transformation

Am I correct in assuming that any sequence of SVG transforms T1...Tn can be replaced by a single generic transform whose matrix is obtained by multiplying the matrices M1 * ... * Mn, where Mi corresponds to transform Ti?

I'm asking because I'm trying to replace the sequence of transforms below with a single one:

- scale (1, y)
- translate (0, max)
- scale (1, -1)

If my assumption were correct, this would be the same as the matrix (1, 0, 0, -y, 0, y*max) transform, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you've got the right idea with multiplying them together, but you need to make sure you're multiplying the full 3x3 [affine transformation matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Affine_transformations) using matrix multiplication from linear algebra, and you must make sure the order is the correct way around, i.e, starting with the first transformation you must put the matrices *right to left*.

So the correct matrix multiplication is

```
[1  0 0][1 0 0][1 0 0]     [1  0  0]
[0 -1 0][0 1 m][0 y 0]  =  [0 -y -m]
[0  0 1][0 0 1][0 0 1]     [0  0  1]
```

or (1,0,0,0,-y,-m) in svg notation

Comment: Ah, thanks!  So basically I got everything right, except for the multiplication order.

Comment: Actually I think if you do it the other way around you should get (1,0,0,0,-y,y*max).